# How to kill a process on no output for some period of time

Tags: linux

I've written a program that is suppose to run for a long time and it outputs the progress to `stdout`, however, under some circumstances it begins to hang and the easiest thing to do is to restart it.

My question is: Is there a way to do something that would kill the process only if it had no output for a specific number of seconds?

I have started thinking about it, and the only thing that comes to mind is something like this:

```
./application > output.log &
tail -f output.log
```

then create script which would look at the date and time of the last modification on `output.log` and restart the whole thing.

But it looks very tedious, and i would hate to go through all that if there were an existing command for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a standard utility to do it, but a good start for a one-liner would be:

```
timeout=10; if [ -z "`find output.log -newermt @$[$(date +%s)-${timeout}]`" ]; then killall -TERM application; fi
```

At least, this will avoid the tedious part of coding a more complex script.

Some hints:

- Using the `find` utility to compare the last modification date of the output.log file against a time reference.
- The time reference is returned by `date` utility as the current time in seconds (`+%s`) since EPOCH (1970-01-01 UTC).
- Using `bash` $[] operation to subtract the $timeout value (10 seconds on the example)
- If no output is returned from the above `find`, then the file wasn't changed for more than 10 seconds. This will trigger a true in the `if` condition and the `killall` command will be executed.

You can also set an `alias` for that, using:

```
alias kill_application='timeout=10; if [ -z "`find output.log -newermt @$[$(date +%s)-${timeout}]`" ]; then killall -TERM application; fi';
```

And then use it whenever you want by just issuing the command `kill_application`

If you want to automatically restart the application without human intervention, you can install a `crontab` entry to run every minute or so and also issue the application restart command after the `killall` (Probably you may also want to change the -TERM to -KILL, just in case the application becomes unresponsive to handleable signals).

Answer (score 3):

The `inotifywait` could help here, it efficiently  waits  for  changes  to  files. The exit status can be checked to identify if the event (`modify`) occurred in the specified interval of time.

```
$ inotifywait -e modify -t 10 output.log 
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
$ echo $?
2
```

Some related info from man:

```
OPTIONS
   -e <event>, --event <event>
       Listen for specific event(s) only.

   -t <seconds>, --timeout <seconds>
       Exit  if  an  appropriate  event  has  not occurred within <seconds> seconds.

EXIT STATUS
   2  The -t option was used and an event did not occur in the specified interval of time.

EVENTS
   modify A watched file or a file within a watched directory was written to.
```